# How to update taxonomy field with array of terms?

Tags: 8, taxonomy-terms

I am having a body like this

```
{
    "userid": 435,
    "territories_id":[176,139]
}
```

Where userid is the drupal user id. And I need to update field **field_user_territory** which is a taxonomy field. I do not want earlier territories to go instead I need to update with 2 more territories.

This is the code I tried.

```
foreach ($territories_id as $territory_id) {

     
        
            $user = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::load($userid);
            $user->field_user_territory->target_id = $territory_id;
            $user->save();
        
    }
```

But here the earlier territories got vanished.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to append the field items:

```
$user = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::load($userid);
foreach ($territories_id as $territory_id) {
  // full version (works with autocomplete in an IDE)
  $user->get('field_user_territory')->appendItem(['target_id' => $territory_id]);
  // short version in array syntax
  // $user->field_user_territory[] = $territory_id;
}
$user->save();
```

Comment: Thanks it worked

Comment: Is there any way to avoid duplication ?

Comment: Sorry, moved the second version in a comment.